# RealmSwift No Such File or directory

Tags: swift, realm

I've been trying to install the new version of realm 0.92.3. I've followed every single step from the tutorial, but still keep getting the error.

```
btplpinoudaynpddpsugjevklbvh/Build/Products/Debug-
iphonesimulator/MyBook.app/Frameworks/RealmSwift.framework/strip-
frameworks.sh: No such file or directory
```

Any idea as to why its not compiling, i am new to realm
[image: Frameworks Added]
[image: run script added]
[image: search path set]

Comment: Are you sure you copied the framework to the project ? (if you checked "Copy if needed" when dragging the Framework to the project)

Answer (score 0):

since i was updating from version 0.92.2, there seems to be some issues when replacing files. but once i deleted the derived data folder(Preference > Location) & clean up (Shift + cmd + k) and redid all the steps, it compiled.